# Cross join not working correctly in pandas

Tags: pandas, cross-join

I have 2 pandas tables table_a and table_b both tables contains same columns ID and no_of_employee

I need to do cross on both tables I tried below syntax

```
table_a['key'] = 1
table_b['key'] = 1

df_detail = pd.merge(table_a, table_b, on ='key').drop("key", 1)
```

but it didn't worked correctly gave below output containg four columns:

```
['ID_x','no_of_employee_x','ID_y','no_of_employee_y']
```

But I only need 2 column in final table given below:

`Id` and `no_of_employee`

What is the correct syntax? I tried to find but didn't got one.

Comment: are you using pyspark or pandas?

Comment: @samkart Pandas I'm using

Comment: looks like you don't need a cross join, use outer join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is probably what u want

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = [(1, 15), (7, 12)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1, columns=['id', 'employee_no'])

d2 = [(1, 3), (4, 8)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2, columns=['id', 'employee_no'])

df_cross = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', sort=True)

print(df_cross)

   id  employee_no
0   1            3
1   1           15
2   4            8
3   7           12
```

Comment: sorry it's pandas table not pyspark can  you please provide syntax for pandas

Comment: i update the answer. if that not exactily what u expected. u can share some examples.